# How to change BottomNavigationBar background colour?

Tags: android, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app

Im making a simple app with tab bars. I need to change Bottom Navigation Bar's background colour to blue. The rest of the app should be in white background and navigation bar should be blue backgrounded. How should I do that?
Setting canvasColor in ThemeData didnt work.

Heres my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
    return MyAppState();
}
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{

  int _selectedPage = 0;
  final _pageOptions = [
    Text('Item1'),
    Text('Item2'),
    Text('Item3')
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'sddsd',

      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        fontFamily: "Google Sans"

      ),

      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title:Text("LQ2018"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),

      body: _pageOptions[_selectedPage],

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        fixedColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        currentIndex: _selectedPage,
        onTap: (int index){
          setState(() {
            _selectedPage= index;
          });
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle), title: Text('Players')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.whatshot), title: Text('Trending')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.access_time), title: Text('Highlights'))
        ]
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{

  int _selectedPage = 0;
  final _pageOptions = [
    Text('Item1'),
    Text('Item2'),
    Text('Item3')
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'sddsd',

      theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          fontFamily: "Google Sans"

      ),

      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title:Text("LQ2018"),
          //backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),

        body: _pageOptions[_selectedPage],

        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(

            //fixedColor: Colors.blueAccent,
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,

            currentIndex: _selectedPage,
            onTap: (int index){
              setState(() {
                _selectedPage= index;
              });
            },
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle), title: Text('Players'),backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.whatshot), title: Text('Trending'),backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.access_time), title: Text('Highlights'),backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent)
            ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes! Working perfectly fine. Thanks

Comment: So I get that it answers the question but I don't understand why the BottomNavigationBar has a `backgroundColor` as well then? 
I assume that it has a background that is blocked out by the Items? If so, why does adding a backgroundColor to a single item change the color for all of them? From reading the docs (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar/backgroundColor.html) it has to do with `shifting` but I still don't really understand it...

Comment: Hello ,@Thiemo It is an implementation design decision. may be it is a material design requirement but not sure !, if you are familiar with the flutter source code and still see it  worth it  ,feel free to make your adjustment and send a PR to the GitHub repo.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your BottomNavigationBar in a Theme and set the canvasColor in data of the theme.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
              canvasColor: Colors.blue,
              textTheme: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .copyWith(caption: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54))),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            currentIndex: currentIndex,
            fixedColor: Colors.green,
            onTap: (value) {},
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add),),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks and I found adding "type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting" property and then setting up background colour for Tabitems is easy :)