# Flutter - Change Smartphone Navbar background color

Tags: flutter

I'm creating an app with a dark theme, and I want to change the smartphone navigation bar's background color.

[image]

I tried a lot of possibilities to darken this bar, but none of these has managed to solve my problem.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53579125/how-to-change-bottomnavigationbar-background-colour) will answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this under your widget build method

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black,
  systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
));
```

Answer (score -1):

no you can't change this
this is default android setting